# How can I find the possible values for a function parameter or class property of a library/framework?

Tags: frameworks, libraries

I will try to explain my problem with an example but my question is not only for this particular case.

I am trying to use the React Mde library. On their documentation page at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mde#react-mde-props it says to customize the toolbar you can set the `toolbarCommands` prop to an array of strings listing the toolbar options you want.

My question is how can I find the possible string values I can put there? In their example they only mention `[["code", "bold"], ["italic"]]`.

As I said at the beginning I would like to know if there is a general method of finding out the possible values in such situations. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the source code of the dependency in your IDE,
here check : node-modules/react-mde/lib/js/commands/default-commands/default.js